# List all users that are not admin. I get all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'am using Identity in asp.net. I want to display all users that are not in the role Admin.

I can get all users like this

```
var userView = await UserManager.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToListAsync();
return View(userView);
```

Trying to get all users that are not in the role admin (users without role).

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Admin");
var userView = UserManager.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.All(r => r.RoleId != role.Id));
return View(userView);
```

Still get all users. Users with role Admin and users without role. I can see I have 3 users in `var role` when I debug.

Comment: What is the type of `role.Id`, out of interest?

Comment: Your code returns all users that have at least one non-admin role. I suspect, your administrators have more than one role. You should use `!m.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id)` instead - users that don't have any admin role. Although I suspect `!m.Roles.Any(r => r == role)` would also work

Comment: If `m.Roles` has the same item type as `db.Roles`, then why compare `r.RoleId` to `role.Id`? If they are different types, please edit your question with additional information on the used properties.

Answer (score -1):

```
var role = RoleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Admin");
var userView = UserManager.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.All(r => r.RoleId != role.Id));
return View(userView);
```

-Try to replace the "db" to "RoleManager". it works for me.